# Will a big array slow down performance in Angular 8?

Tags: arrays, angular, performance

I have text file in my assets folder with 60000 words. On page load this file is loaded into an array. The array is used to pick random words from it (a 100 words maximum). I'm using the Filter method for it. I'm not going to perform any inserts/updates/deletes to the list. I only use a Filter on it.

Locally every runs nice and quick, but I don't know whether performance will suffer from loading a large list of 60000 items in the long run every time that page loads.

Does anyone have experience with using large lists like this in Angular and tell me if this is fine or I should look for another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes only a *fraction* of a second to iterate 60,000 times.

```js
const t1 = performance.now();
for(let x = 0; x < 60000; x++) {};
const t2 = performance.now();
console.log(`${t2 - t1} milliseconds`);
```

The *majority* of any performance *lag* will be in the time it takes to download and `JSON.stringify()` the response. I would *bundle* the collection of words as part of the JavaScript source code instead of performing a HTTP request, but either way the performance impact is minor at best.

If the server is configured properly then the HTTP GET request for the assets file will be *cached* in the browser. So any future requests will happen without any lag.